# Find Current Location Android 6.0

Tags: android, permissions, location

i have a problem to find current position with android 6.0 (sdk 23).

In main activity i wrote:

```
       locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        locationListener = new LocationListener() {

            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

textView.append("\n " + location.getLongitude() + " " + location.getLatitude());

            }

            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
                Intent i = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                startActivity(i);
            }

        };

        configure_list();
```

implementing also on request permission result:

```
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case 10:
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    // permission granted

                } else {
                    // permission denied

                }
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    public void configure_list() {
        // first check for permissions
        if 

(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(Applicazione.getInstance().getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(Applicazione.getInstance().getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,Manifest.permission.INTERNET} ,10);
        }
        return;
    }

    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates("gps", 5000, 0, locationListener);

}
```

But current location is always 0. Is there an error? Can anyone suggest me something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use Fused Location API

https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderApi